# ReCharts.Js Shaded Areas For full height of Chart (and consistent with Brush, dataMax)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, d3.js, recharts

I am trying to create an area that is to be shaded based on the presents of a key. I want the shading to be from min-to-max in the Y-axis and I want the max to be dependent on the current-local max of the dataset (with respect to Brush).

I tried to play around with the internals of ReChart.js such methods as getTicksOfAxis and getValueByDataKey because I know that the Y-axis already knows the local max, so I wouldn't have to reinvent the wheel. Anyone have any solutions

[Fiddle With Me](https://jsfiddle.net/gautamnaik1994/nhr9apd3/)

```js
const {ComposedChart, Area ,LineChart, Line, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, Tooltip, Legend,Brush} = Recharts;
const data = [
      {name: 'Page A', pv: 2400, max: 10800},
      {name: 'Page q', pv: 4800, max: 10800},
      {name: 'Page w',  pv: 1398},
      {name: 'Page e',  pv: 0},
      //I don't want this part max to squish the pv values since Max should be of the local max.
      {name: 'Page r',  pv: 300, max: 10800},
      {name: 'Page t',  pv: 200, max: 10800},
      {name: 'Page y',  pv: 0},
      {name: 'Page u',  pv: 500},
      {name: 'Page i',  pv: 1398, max: 10800},
      {name: 'Page o',  pv: 4300, max: 10800},
      {name: 'Page p', pv: 10800 },
      {name: 'Page [', pv: 3908 },
      {name: 'Page ]',pv: 4800, max: 10800},
      {name: 'Page F', pv: 3800, max: 10800},
      {name: 'Page G', pv: 4300, max: 10800},
];
const SimpleLineChart = React.createClass({
 render () {
   return (
     <ComposedChart width={600} height={300} data={data}
            margin={{top: 5, right: 30, left: 20, bottom: 5}}>
       <XAxis dataKey="name"/>
       <YAxis type="number"/>
       <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3"/>
       <Tooltip/>
       <Legend />
       <Line type="monotone" dataKey="pv" stroke="#8884d8" activeDot={{r: 8}}/>
       <Area type="monotone" dataKey="max" stroke="#8884d8" activeDot={{r: 8}}/>
       <Brush/>
      </ComposedChart>
    );
  }
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <SimpleLineChart />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: why is the fiddle different from the question code? There is no area in the fiddle.

Comment: if you draw an image of what you want to see based on the supplied data would clarify a lot

Answer (score 0):

[Suitable Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmPbP.jpg)
The graph provided is what I was aiming for where the shaded area is representative of some datapoint. I was able to create a sawtooth appearance (working with the brush) by providing a method for the "local-max" e.i:

---

`let data=[{
    line-graph:<arbitrary_value>,
    shaded-areas:local_max()},...];
 let local_max=()=>{return this.state.localMax}`

---

I then had to discover the local maxes, which involves getting the brushes start/endIndex and saving those to state.